# Handle condtional parameter for constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

My program works this way: if the user inputs the data path parameter, it will use that path. If not, it uses the current path of the program.

The constructor is `Server(QString path)`.

Obviously, this won't work:

```
if(!isDefaultPath)
   Server server(userPath);
else
   Server server(programPath);
server.doSmth();
```

Currently, I do like this

```
Server serverDefault(programPath);
Server serverCustomized(userPath);
if(!isDefaultPath)
       serverCustomized.doSmth();
    else
       serverDefault.doSmth();
```

But I feel this ain't nice. Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious way is

```
Server server(isDefaultPath? programPath : userPath )
```

Note also that even if you have a more advanced logic that does not fit into a simple `?:` operator, you can always implement it to find the needed parameter as string and only then initialize the constructor:

```
path = programPath;
if (....) path = ...
else ...
path = path + ...;

Server server(path);
```

One more approach if the constructor calls are drastically different, use a pointer

```
std::unique_ptr pServer;
if (...) pServer = std::make_unique<Server>(new Server("a", "b"));
else pServer = std::make_unique<Server>(new Server(137));
Server server = *pServer;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use ternary operator:

```
Server server(isDefaultPath ? programPath : userPath);
```